# Avoid code duplication between django Q expression and as python code

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a very complex property on a model

```py
ALLOWED_STATES = {1,2,3}
class X(models.Model):
    a = models.BooleanField()
    b = models.ForeignKey('Y', on_delete=model.CASCADE)
    c = models.IntegerField()
    d = models.IntegerField()
    @property
    def can_delete(self)
        # this goes on for 6 and clause
        return self.a and self.b.c and self.c in ALLOWED_STATES and self.d != 5 and ..
```

I also need this property in an annotate() call and filter()

```py
#in one endpoint
qs = X.objects.filter(...).annoate(can_delete=ExpressionWrapper(Q(a=True, b__c=True, c__in=ALLOWED_STATES,...) & ~Q(d=5), output_field=models.BooleanField())
```

I wonder if there is a way to unify these forms of this same property into one, without calling can_delete in python after I've fetched the rows. These two forms have become a bit of a maintainability issue as PM keeps on changing the definition of can_delete.

Status update: neither of these answers quite solve the problem. I end up with a custom manager that has a `annotate_can_delete()` method. At least this will keep the Q expression and python code in the same place, making it easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

What if you used the Q object when computing `can_delete()`?

For example, change `can_delete()` to this:

```
    @property
    def can_delete(self)
        return X.objects \
            .annotate(can_delete_qs=ExpressionWrapper(Q(a=True, b__c=True, c__in=ALLOWED_STATES,...) & ~Q(d=5), output_field=models.BooleanField()) \
            .get(id=self.id) \
            .can_delete_qs
```

Warning: untested code.

This would have the cost that every call to `can_delete()` now requires a database call, even if you have the object in memory. However, since you already have a way of using annotate to compute this for entire querysets, you would only ever call this for a single object at a time, which isn't that bad.

It would have the benefit that you could use the same Q expression in both places.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the object for a can_delete annotation inside the property:

```
def can_delete(self)
     if hasattr( self, 'can_delete_qs'):  # was this object annotated?
         return self.can_delete_qs        # if so return the annotation value
     # this goes on for 6 and clause
     return self.a and self.b.c and ...   # as before
```

This will avoid an unnecessary DB call if the previous query has already obtained the information.

Take care, though, that the information which gave rise to the annotation might have been changed in the DB by the time you refer to `obj.can_delete`. If this is possible and the consequences of deleting something which in the DB now evaluates `can_delete_qs = False` are serious, you must not cache this information but rather re-evaluate it with a DB query every time.

For maintainability in place of efficiency, remove the Python evaluation and replace the rest of the property with Nico ODell's suggestion. Further, define the Q object in one place (DRY) and import it wherever it's needed

```
CAN_DELETE_Q = Q(a=True, b__c=True, c__in=ALLOWED_STATES,...) & ~Q(d=5)

from wherever import CAN_DELETE_Q

...
    .annotate(can_delete_qs=ExpressionWrapper( CAN_DELETE_Q) ...
```

something I don't know, is whether you can define a Q expression before Django has fully initialized its Database. If not, you need a dynamic import or a lazy evaluation to delay the evaluation until after Django is up and running.